# Okhttpclient first call creating new connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp, spring-cloud-feign

We are using springboot app and using feign-okhttp for rest calls, everything is working fine but performance stats are not that good. Performance scenario is based on single user calling the api maybe only 2-3 times a day. I know okhttpclient uses connection pool as default with 5 ideal connection. But on every first hit the getconnection() method of okhttpclient is returning 0 , so in every case it is creating a new connection.

I want a way to load the okhttp connection pool with some warm threads so that first call will take the connection from there. I have checked dispatcher but not very confident to use a executor of my own.